# python3 import error: while running with sudo -u <user> python3

Tags: python, linux, python-3.5, sudo

For my python script I need to change the user. Therefore I start the script with:
`sudo -u eval python3 run_aufgabe2.py`there is no problem running the script until I import modules from the same directory, then I get an import-error:

```
$ Traceback (most recent call last):
$     File "run_aufgabe2.py", line 5, in <module>
$ import aufgabe2
$ ImportError: No module named 'aufgabe2'
```

Running the script without `sudo -u eval`, the import is working and the script is running without errors. I first thought about a permission problem, maybe the the user `eval` can not read the file `aufgabe2.py`, so I changed the rights:

```
$ -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 3583 Apr 12 09:08 aufgabe2.py
$ -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root    0 Apr 12 09:08 __init__.py
$ -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  432 Apr 12 09:43 run_aufgabe2.py
```

But still the same error, I can not think of anything more, but I am sure I am missing something.

---

Edit 1:

I have to kinds of shell scripts to run the python scripts.

Bash script for simple scripts:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd $1
sudo -u eval python3 $2
```

Expect script for dynamic userinputs:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
cd [lindex $argv 0]
spawn sudo -u eval python3 [lindex $argv 1]
#[...]
```

As @FlyingTeller hast mentioned in his commands, I have the option to add the current working dir to the PYTHONPATH variable. I couldn't get this running, maybe someone can help me with the shell scripts.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Try `from . import aufgabe2`

Comment: nearly the same error

Comment: Try to do `print(sys.path)` and see which directories are in there. Usually the directory you are running the script in get's added there. Seems like `sudo -u eval` messed with that somehow

Comment: And you can fix that by doing `import sys; sys.path.append(".")` if it is indeed missing.

Comment: Seams like that's the problem, the directory is not listed.

Comment: thanks to @FlyingTeller that was the problem an its working with Graipher solution. Is there a way to add path with a shell scrip before starting the python script?

Comment: `export PYTHONPATH=<path to directory of aufgabe2>:$PYTHONPATH` will add the directory to your pythonpath. you can put in in your `~/.bashrc`, write it in the command line, or put it in a script that you source before invoking your python script. I am not sure however if it will work when you change user with `sudo -h` (cannot test due to missing sudo privileges)

Comment: @FlyingTeller `import sys` was a nice workaround, but I need a permant solution. I tried to add the dir to the PYTHONPATH bevor starting the scripts. But I couldn't get this running. I have added the shell scripts int he original post. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @FlyingTeller has mentioned, usually the directory you are running the script in, get's added to `sys.path`. Seems like `sudo -u eval` messed with that somehow. The solution is adding path manually:

```
import sys
sys.path.append(".")
```